# Monogame Virtual gamepad not responding to touch in Android

Tags: android, monogame, gamepad

Is there any problem in Monogame GamePad Class for Android. There is no Android version of project files in samples that use gamepad class (VirtualGamePad, RockRain). I try using this class in my Android project but it is not responding to touch. 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Someone asked a similar question the other day here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/57396/monogame-sample-virtual-dpad-not-responding-to-touch-in-android-device No solution though, so it could very well be a bug in MonoGame.

Comment: You are right. I am tyring fix it. There are more problems than one.